# flutter how display time and date

Tags: flutter, dart

I get time and date from API from server as string  :

```
"dateOBDCommand": "2021-07-13T13:15:54.000000Z"
```

I would like to display only to user :

```
2021-07-13  13:15:54
```

my code :

```
return Card(

      child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                  title: Container(
                      height: 30,
                      child: Text("${obd.description}")),
                  subtitle: Text("${obd.dateOBDCommand}"),
                  trailing: Text("${obd.value}"),
              )
```

How I can do that ??

Comment: hey @lucky which plugin your are using for listning obd data in flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DateTime and DateFormat class, can implement like below.

- add a [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) to pubspec.yaml

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    String dateOBDCommand = '2021-07-13T13:15:54.000000Z';
    DateTime date = DateTime.parse(dateOBDCommand);
    String result = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s').format(date);

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Text(
          'before : ' + dateOBDCommand,
        ),
        Text(
          'after : ' + result.toString(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first parse string date to DateTime Object and then format it according to your formatter. Here is doc link

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DateTime` and `DateFormat` from the intl package.

For example:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

...

String dateString = "2021-07-13T13:15:54.000000Z";
final date = DateTime.parse(dateString);
final format = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s');
print(format.format(date));
```